# Getting Error in the following Groovy Code.. Whats the problem?

Tags: groovy

HI all, the following code does not getting executed, the code is

```
class Invoice{
        List items
        Date date
}
class LineItem{
        Product product
        int count
        int total(){
                return product.dollar * count
        }
}
class Product{
        String name
        def dollar
}
def ulcDate = new Date(107,0,1)
def ulc = new Product(name:'ULC', dollar:200)
def ve = new Product(name:'Visual Editor',dollar:500)
def invoices =[new Invoice(date:ulcDate, items: [new LineItem(count:5, product:ulc),new LineItem(count:2, product:ve)]), new Invoice(date:[107,1,1],items:[new LineItem(count:4,product:ve)])]
assert [200,500,400] == invoices.items*.total()
```

This file name is `Test.groovy` and when i execute like this `groovy Test` i'm getting an error like this :

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.total() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: tail(), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), getAt(java.util.Collection), getAt(int), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String)
    at In1.run(In1.groovy:20)
```

Even though i have defined the `total()` method, it throws an error? Whats the reason for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the line:

```
assert [200,500,400] == invoices.items*.total()
```

`invoices.items` returns a `List<List<LineItem>>` so `invoices.items*.total()` fails because the outer `List` doesn't have a `total()` method.

If you want to get the total of each LineItem, just remove the outer `List` by calling `flatten()`

```
assert [1000, 1000, 2000] == invoices.items.flatten()*.total()
```

If you want to get the total value of each invoice, try the following

```
assert [2000, 2000] == invoices.items*.sum { it.total() }
```

Comment: or `assert [ 2000, 2000 ] == invoices.items*.sum { it.total1() }`

Comment: @Don! how do you say `List<List<LineItem>>` this what is been returned by `invoices.items` ?

Comment: @Ant are you asking me how do I know this is what is being returned, or why is this being returned?

Comment: @Don: no I'm asking How do you know.... and it will be good if you explain why this is being returned too...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you typed cut'n'paste from your code you have a typo...

```
class LineItem{
    Product product
    int count
    int total**1**(){
            return product.dollar * count
    }
}
```

Remove the '1' from the method name and retry.

Comment: However i have Typos in my question, Sorry this is not the correct answer, the correct answer is mentioned by Don!

Comment: +1 vote to restore to 0. Whoever voted this down was unfair - you have to respond to the question as it's presented.